# Trackdown recently sent and received api calls

Tags: api, leads

Where can I see list of all sent api calls and received ones? I want to find leads which were recently updated with api calls (I send lead id inside api call)

Comment: If you use specific user for your integration purposes, you would easily be able to tell which leads were update by API users. Otherwise I am afraid the method used for the update is not something that is captured...You can run a report on API usage but it will not get you what you are asking in your question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you're not monitoring the API user in the debug logs, there is no place where the API calls are logged. You need to implement that functionality yourself using apex and a custom object to store the entries with any relevant data that you want to keep.